# Use Authenticated Google Client instance for multiple services

Tags: php, laravel, google-search-console, google-client

I am creating google client instance and authenticating it once and fetching required data. Afterwards if I want to use that same instance of Google client for some other service , how can I achieve it ?

webmasterMain route is my redirect uri registered in google webmaster .

```
    public function webmasterMain(Request $request)
    {
        $requestData = $request->all();
        if ($request->isMethod('POST') || isset($requestData['code'])) {
            $google_redirect_url = env('APP_URL') . '/user/webmasterMain';
            $gClient = new \Google_Client();
            $gClient->setAccessType("offline");// to get refresh token after expiration of access token
            $gClient->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
            $gClient->setApplicationName(config('services.google.app_name'));
            $gClient->setClientId(config('services.google.client_id'));
            $gClient->setClientSecret(config('services.google.client_secret'));
            $gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
            $gClient->setDeveloperKey(config('services.google.api_key'));
            $gClient->setScopes(array(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters',
            ));
            $google_oauthV2 = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
            if ($request->get('code')) {
                $gClient->authenticate($request->get('code'));
                $request->session()->put('token', $gClient->getAccessToken());
            }
            if ($request->session()->get('token')) {
                $gClient->setAccessToken($request->session()->get('token'));
            }

            if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
                $inst = new Google_Service_Webmasters($gClient);
                $res = $inst->sites->listSites();
                $sites = $res->getSiteEntry();
                $siteUrl = [];
                foreach ($sites as $key => $site) {
                    $siteUrl = array_add($siteUrl, $key, ['site_name'=>$site['siteUrl'], 'site_permission_level' => $site['permissionLevel']]);
                }
                $sites = (((array)$siteUrl));
                return view('User::webmasterMain')->with(['data' => $sites]);
            } else {
                //For Guest user, get google login url
                $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
                return redirect()->to($authUrl);
            }
        }
        return view('User::webmasterMain');
    }
```

Now suppose I want to get the authenticated $gClient for service like Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest , then how can I make $client = $gClient for this next request ?

```
    public function query(Request $request){
//suppose $client is the same instance which was previously authenticated and stored in $gClient
    $website = "http://example.com/";
                $searchAnalytics = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
                $searchAnalytics->setStartDate('2017-03-01');
                $searchAnalytics->setEndDate('2017-03-31');
                $searchAnalytics->setDimensions(['page']);
                $searchAnalytics->setSearchType('web');
    `$results = $client->searchanalytics->query($website, $searchAnalytics);`
    return $results->getRows();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer , no need to save the instance or do anything but, follow this :

1. Create a Google Client Object.
2. At first time authenticating save the accessToken from google client object by getAccessToken().
3. Use the same access token and set Access token in this google client.
4. now you can use this google client object for any service.

First time authenticating:

```
$gClient = new \Google_Client();
```

//after authenticating

```
$request->session()->put('token', $gClient->getAccessToken());
```

Now we can use this access token in any google service call:

```
 $gClient = new \Google_Client();

        if ($request->session()->get('token')) {
            $gClient->setAccessToken($request->session()->get('token'));
        }

        $client = new Google_Service_Webmasters($gClient);
```